# exporting html page to pdf using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
answer = $('#text').html();
doc.fromHTML(answer,10,10,{
'width' :7,

});
 doc.output('datauri');
```

I am importing html content to pdf, i getting the content in answer , but nothing happens no pdf is generated? All the files are included correctly.I have used **alert(answer)** and it is showing the html content correctly

Comment: Did you check out the jsfiddle I included in my answer? This shows a pdf being generated using your code above. Is this not what you were expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full HTML it's difficult to see what the problem is here, but my best guess is that jQuery can't find the element with the Id 'text' in the line `answer = $('#text').html();`. Here's a JSFiddle using your code that's working correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/mnrL7/

Comment: i have checked it using alert(answer) it is showing the html content

Comment: Are you able to post an example?